# Using AWS S3 to Share Folders

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

**Use Case:** shutting down on-premise WingFTP Secure Server and moving 50+ folders to AWS S3. Need to provide access to 120 end users outside my organization.

**Challenges**:

1. How do I limit end user access to their specific folder(s) in the s3 bucket? 
   I can't expose one users data to another.
2. Do not want to spin up a 3rd party application like FileCloud (no offense to 
   FileCloud), nor do I want to spin-up an EC2 running WingFTP.
3. Lastly, not intent to set up 120+ IAM end user accounts.

Thanks for any feedback!

Scott

Comment: How many files and how often will they upload? Is a web page satisfactory, or do you need an easily-automated solution?

Comment: The uploads by customers is very limited, mostly this is for downloads by the customer. Files are retrieved at least once per month by the customer, and approximately  8 files per. All files are relatively small...100KB each.

Comment: Oh! If it is for downloads, then I'd simply make it a web-based download page with Cognito authentication. Very little code would be required.

Answer (score 2):

I congratulate you for helping to eliminate FTP from the world!

You should *not* give the users IAM accounts. IAM should only be used for users and applications within your own organisation.

Instead, you need a way to **authenticate** the end users and then give them appropriate (temporary) **access to Amazon S3**.

One way would be to use **Amazon Cognito** to authenticate users. You can then generate temporary credentials that grant access to 'their folder' within an S3 bucket. They can use these credentials with the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), or an application like CyberDuck or simply a web page that allows them to upload a file. If they want to automate the upload, then the CLI is the way to go.

Another way would be to have a simple application that authenticates the users (however you want to do that), then generates **Pre-Signed URLs** that allows them to upload files via a web page to their specific folder.

Comment: Thanks John! Now working with a AWS PS and an AWS Premier Partner to architect the solution.

Comment: "You should not give the users IAM accounts". Why not ?

Comment: @JulienFr IAM There is a limit of 5000 IAM Users in an AWS Account. An IAM User is what your internal staff would use to access AWS, create resources, configure infrastructure, access S3, etc. They are not intended for 'end-users', although if you work with a small number of external partners, you could give them IAM User credentials to access specific Amazon S3 buckets to exchange data. In the case of this question, with 120+ users, it's really becoming more of an 'application' that deserves its own system (eg password resets, logging) rather than using IAM Users.